# Apple Push Notification can not send push on AWS EC2

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I sent push notification by simple push on local server is success and app get message normally.

But push notification can not sent on AWS EC2, it sent to Android normally, I check device token is correct.

I don't know why, please help me!

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what do you mean by sending notification on AWS EC 2? I am not sure I get your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue is some device token is invalid, so that, it is can not send push notification any more. I use Houston on Web server Ruby. I changed push instead of write, and now, it is work normally.